# google map not showing on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, google-map

I am trying a very simple exercise to display a google map on visualforce page.
But nothing is showing up.

Below is my page code -

```
<apex:page controller="SampleLocation">

 <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>



</apex:page>
```

Below is console log

[image]

Below is Network log,

[image]

when I preview the page, nothing is shown.

when I save the exact same code in separate html file ( after removing apex:page tag) the code works just fine. I am sure that there is no issue with the API key.

any idea what is going wrong here ?

Comment: I suggest in future you post your code as text (and use the {} to format it). That way people can take and run an exact copy to try to help you.

Comment: corrected and added page code as text

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I use your code with the div set to a hard-coded size:

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"/>
```

the map renders.

Remember that your Visualforce page includes a lot of Salesforce CSS and the header and sidebar HTML (that are not present if you just strip out the content into a html file). So you will need to figure out the appropriate CSS styling to apply to get the result you want.

Comment: it worked, Thx!!